# Is this sentence grammatical and does it make sense?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

> "The key to understanding big data is that data has to be managed **so that it can meet the business requirement a given solution is designed to support**" (Hurwitz, Nugent, Halper, & Kaufman, 2013, p. 1).

Is this sentence correctly crafted? What does the part after *so that* mean?

Reference:

Hurwitz, J. S., Nugent, A., Halper, F., & Kaufman, M. (2013). *Big data for dummies*. Hoboken, NJ: Wiley.

Comment: It's grammatical; just add a 'which' after 'requirement'. The meaning is very much obvious and ' so that' is an adverbial subordinating conjunction meaning ' with the intent that'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar of that sentence is OK. Its meaning is a little hard to understand, especially without the rest of the context, because it is pretty vague, and full of non-specific vocabulary words.

The words following "so that":

> "it can meet the business requirement a given solution is designed to
>   support"

are a clause defining the way that big data must be managed.

In short, it (the big data) must be managed "so that it meets a requirement". The rest of the words are there to describe that requirement. It is a "business" requirement, and the requirement is what "a given solution is designed to support."

Essentially what this sentence means is,

> "You have to manage your big data in such a way that it helps you."

But that doesn't sound like I have a PhD in Business, does it?